# Docker - php-7.0.27-apache soap install issue

Tags: php, apache, docker, dockerfile

I'm having trouble getting SOAP installed on my php-7.0.27-apache container.We get the following error.

> There is E: Package 'php-soap' has no installation candidate as well
>   and returned 100 as exit code.

Here is my Dockerfile -

```
FROM php:7.0.27-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libpng-dev zlib1g-dev \
    && a2enmod headers \
    && a2enmod rewrite

RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev \
                       php-soap

RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
```

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/315#issuecomment-399461699

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Not Working on my case, I'm using php:7.0.27-apache

Answer (score 0):

Try this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) soap
```

if you build it this way:

```
docker build --tag stackoverflow .
```

and run this way:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint="" stackoverflow /bin/sh
```

you will be logged into CLI and may check installed extensions this way:

```
php -m
```

that gives `soap` under the list of `[PHP Modules]`